# MOSS 2010 - SPWebApplication.Lookup function error

Tags: moss

I am trying to execute the following code:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Items["FormDigestValidated"] = true;

            SPWebApplication webApp = SPWebApplication.Lookup(new Uri(string.Format("http://{0}", swebapplicationurl)));
            SPSiteCollection sites = webApp.Sites;
            Site.Dispose();

        });
```

It ends up with error as follows:

"
This operation can be performed only on a computer that is joined to a server farm by users who have permissions in SQL Server to read from the configuration database. To connect this server to the server farm, use the SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard, located on the Start menu in Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Products.
"

I am stuck. Please help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve this issue by doing the following:

1. Create an Application Pool
2. Select Advance settings
3. Set .Net Framework version [setting v2.0 worked for me]
   Under Process Model ---> Identity
4. Provide Custom account. provide the username & password of the user who has the premissions on SharePoint Config database in the SQL Server.
5. Set Load User Profile to TRUE.
6. Reset IIS, Clear cashe.

It will work